# Count existing number of rows

Tags: php, mysql

I want to know how many rows were found for a messaging system.

I want to echo something like: "You have X new messages"

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbemployeer";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$_SESSION['dest'];
$user =  $_SESSION["username"];
$sql = "SELECT meldung, sender, datum FROM tbmeldung  WHERE dest='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<b>Meldung:</b> <br> " . $row["meldung"]. " - <br><b>Von:</b> <br>" . $row["sender"]. " <br><b>Datum: </b><br>" . $row["datum"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "No messages found";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Hey there. I removed some unnecessary text and tags, which were too specific

Comment: i think you should add a flag to mark new messages and read messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily use

```
$result->num_rows
```

for this purpose. If you have a flag like `read`, you can use this:

```
$uread = 0;     
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<b>Meldung:</b> <br> " . $row["meldung"]. " - <br><b>Von:</b> <br>" . $row["sender"]. " <br><b>Datum: </b><br>" . $row["datum"]. "<br>";
    if($row["read"] == 0)
      $uread++;
}
```

The unread message count is then in `$uread`.

---

Du kannst einfach

```
$result->num_rows
```

dafür nutzen. Wenn Du ein Flag wie `gelesen` hast, kannst Du das so machen:

```
$uread = 0;     
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<b>Meldung:</b> <br> " . $row["meldung"]. " - <br><b>Von:</b> <br>" . $row["sender"]. " <br><b>Datum: </b><br>" . $row["datum"]. "<br>";
    if($row["gelesen"] == 0)
      $uread++;
}
```

Die Anzahl der ungelesenen Nachrichten ist dann in `$uread` gespeichert.